# Check which network a HUAWEI modem is connected to using an AT command?

Tags: at-command

What is the **AT command** to get the network name on a HUAWEI USB modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If supported by your phone the command AT+COPS? will give you the following results:-

```
<mode>[,<format>,<oper>[,<AcT>]
```

If the phone is powered up and actively camped onto a network the `<oper>` field should contain a 5 or 6 digit number. The first three digits are the Mobile Country Code and the last 2 or 3 are the Mobile Network Code. You can look up the MCC/MNC here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code.

Not all phones support all AT commands so your mileage may vary.